# What is the configuration for overriding default java.io.tmpdir path using spark submit in client and cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to submit a pyspark job in client and cluster mode and I am facing disk quota exceeded issue as the shared directory is full.

In order to overcome this I am trying to use our dedicated usecase directory by providing the following conf:

```
--conf 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.io.tmpdir=/ourpath
--conf 'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.io.tmpdir=/ourpath
```

However I still see job is getting submitted with default tmpdir

Comment: That would depend on what `spark.master` you are using.